# Writing a simple servlet. Getting and sending data via servlet

Tags: java, html, eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

I'm novice in servlets writing. I need to write a simple servlet, it must to input and output data via form. For example, in my servlet I input data about some car(it is consist of such attributes: car name, car size and car color). Servlet must save these data. And also, it must show saved data. Something of servlet I have done, but I still have not knowledges to complete it.

This is a html-code of page, servlet is call from it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cars</title>
</head>

<body><center>Cars</center>

<p>Name: </p>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="car_name"></label>
  <input type="text" name="car_name" id="car_name" />
</form>
<p>Color: </p>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <label for="car_name"></label>
  <input type="text" name="car_color" id="car_color" />
</form>
<p>Size: </p>
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="">
  <label for="car_size"></label>
  <input type="text" name="car_size" id="car_size" />
</form>
<input name="send" type="button" value="Send" />
<input name="get_out" type="button" value="Output" />
<textarea name="output" cols="10" rows="10" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
<fieldset>
<legend>Testing Simple Servlets</legend>
<ul>
  <li><a href="carServlet">carServlet</a> The carServlet is a servlet that
      gets and posts cars' attributes data</li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is a servlet-code(java), (I only begin to realize it):

```
package testPackage;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

@WebServlet("/carServlet")
public class CarServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    //Some code strings which finds items on the web-page
    //Only for example: String item = (String)getItem("car_name");
}
```

How to complete it in order to servlet could save and print out saved data?

Comment: I would suggest that you look for a tutorial on the web and start from there. It is not extremely difficult to make a servlet that returns something. If you have a specific problem with it you can ask a question here again. Possible tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm

Comment: You should also read a tutorial about HTML forms. You have several problems in your HTML: (1) There should be only one form containing all the fields, not many separate forms. (2) The page is not telling the browser where to send the form (your servlet). A form must have an action which is the address of the servlet. (3) There is no submit button. The browser doesn't know what do do if you click one of the buttons. Try starting from [This tutorial](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-tutorial-p1.phtml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package testPackage;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

@WebServlet("/carServlet")
public class CarServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
   }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String carName = request.getParameter("car_name");
        System.out.println("Car Name:" + carName);
   }
}
```

Try this implement your doGet and doPost methods inside your servlet.  You are submitting form via post so you can put your code there.  I just forwarded the get to the post method.  You can access parameters by request.getParameter("parameterName");

Answer (score 0):

HREF links -> You can get your data in the doGet method of your Servlet.
FORM submits -> See your doPost method

Comment: Add more detail and explanation.  You can also use doGet for a form.  And explain HREF (URL).